# Split PHP String to Array

Tags: php, api

I have a string from an API and need to get this into an array to work with it but I don't find any solution to this. I hope someone can help.

the string looks like this:

> ```
>  domain: xxx.de native_domain: xxx.de user: master status: active
> transfer_lock: yes auto_renew: yes delegation: yes ownerc: ASDASD1
> adminc: ASDASD1 techc: ASDASD1 billc: FLOSCH2 created: 2015-08-25
> 10:31:08 modified: 2016-08-20 16:20:15 expire: 2017-08-25 10:31:13
> chreseller_auth: dom-cdmv-zs0f-mpwg auth_info: dns::1/hostname:
> dns1.xxx.com dns::1/hostip: dns::2/hostname: dns2.xxx.com
> dns::2/hostip: dns::3/hostname: dns::3/hostip: dns::4/hostname:
> dns::4/hostip: dns::5/hostname: dns::5/hostip: comment: inserted:
> 2016-01-29 23:46:29
> ```

full string like this

```
domain: xxx.de native_domain: xxx.de user: master status: active
transfer_lock: yes auto_renew: yes delegation: yes ownerc: ASDASD1
adminc: ASDASD1 techc: ASDASD1 billc: FLOSCH2 created: 2015-08-25
10:31:08 modified: 2016-08-20 16:20:15 expire: 2017-08-25 10:31:13
chreseller_auth: dom-cdmv-zs0f-mpwg auth_info: xxxxx_authinfo  
dns::1/hostname:
dns1.xxx.com dns::1/hostip: 1.1.1.1 dns::2/hostname: dns2.xxx.com
dns::2/hostip: 1.1.1.1 dns::3/hostname: dns3.xxx.com 
dns::3/hostip: 1.1.1.1 dns::4/hostname: dns4.xxx.com
dns::4/hostip: 1.1.1.1 dns::5/hostname: dns5.xxx.com dns::5/hostip: 
1.1.1.1 comment: comments inserted:
2016-01-29 23:46:29
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you can split any string to an array using explode() function

Comment: Have you looked at [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function?

Comment: You need to describe how you want it split

Comment: the best split will be 

`code
array( 
 domain -> xxx.de,
 native_domain -> xxx.de 
...
dns -> array(
 1 -> dns1.xxx.com,
 2 -> dns2.xxx.com,
...
),
)
`

Comment: you will Need some more work for this result, but please post how you want it splited exactly. 
For example this line: dns::2/hostip: dns::3/hostname: dns::3/hostip:  which parts should be keys which should be values ?

Comment: in this case it would be a multidimensional array like this

`array(
 dns => array (
  1 -> array (
  hostname => dns1.xxxx.com,
  hostip => 1.1.1.1,
 ),
...
`

Comment: Do you always get the same response back from the API? I.E. it always has domain, always has native_domain, etc. - With the assumption DNS may be a variable amount?

Comment: Where did you get the `hostip => 1.1.1.1` from your give example?

Comment: yes the response is everytime the same structure , only other values ... hostip can be come as api result but can also be empty...

Comment: Could you give us an example where every field is field in, and another where none of the fields are filled. Then give us what you expect to return from each of the examples. Because right now I have half the answer, but am unsure of what some of the results should be.

Comment: best to edit it and put it in your question, but I can kind of understand what you want. I'll post something in a moment.

Comment: added a full string in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you may be able to work a solution off, assuming the response is one full string with the same terms in each response, you have a pre-defined 'needle' array to look through and it splits off the string in between the two needles into its own array. The two needles in this case are two terms to look for, such as the 'domain:' and 'native_domain:'.

```
<?php

$responseStr = "domain: xxx.de native_domain: xxx.de user: master status: active transfer_lock: yes auto_renew: yes delegation: yes ownerc: ASDASD1 adminc: ASDASD1 techc: ASDASD1 billc: FLOSCH2 created: 2015-08-25 10:31:08 modified: 2016-08-20 16:20:15 expire: 2017-08-25 10:31:13 chreseller_auth: dom-cdmv-zs0f-mpwg auth_info: dns::1/hostname: dns1.xxx.com dns::1/hostip: dns::2/hostname: dns2.xxx.com dns::2/hostip: dns::3/hostname: dns::3/hostip: dns::4/hostname: dns::4/hostip: dns::5/hostname: dns::5/hostip: comment: inserted: 2016-01-29 23:46:29";

$responseArray = [
    'domain:',
    'native_domain:',
    'user:',
    'status:',
    'transfer_lock:',
    'auto_renew:',
    'delegation:',
    'ownerc:',
    'adminc:',
    'techc:',
    'billc:',
    'created:',
    'modified:',
    'expire:',
    'chreseller_auth:',
    'auth_info:',
    'dns::1/hostname:',
    'dns::1/hostip:',
    'dns::2/hostname:',
    'dns::2/hostip:',
    'dns::3/hostname:',
    'dns::3/hostip:',
    'dns::4/hostname:',
    'dns::4/hostip:',
    'dns::5/hostname:',
    'dns::5/hostip:',
    'comment:',
    'inserted:',
    "\r"
];


function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);   
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($responseArray) - 1; $i++) {
    $finalArr[$responseArray[$i]] = trim(get_string_between($responseStr, $responseArray[$i], $responseArray[$i+1]));
}
?>

<pre>
<?php var_dump($finalArr); ?>
</pre>
```

This will give the following output;

```
array(28) {
  ["domain:"]=>
  string(6) "xxx.de"
  ["native_domain:"]=>
  string(6) "xxx.de"
  ["user:"]=>
  string(6) "master"
  ["status:"]=>
  string(6) "active"
  ["transfer_lock:"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["auto_renew:"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["delegation:"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["ownerc:"]=>
  string(7) "ASDASD1"
  ["adminc:"]=>
  string(7) "ASDASD1"
  ["techc:"]=>
  string(7) "ASDASD1"
  ["billc:"]=>
  string(7) "FLOSCH2"
  ["created:"]=>
  string(19) "2015-08-25 10:31:08"
  ["modified:"]=>
  string(19) "2016-08-20 16:20:15"
  ["expire:"]=>
  string(19) "2017-08-25 10:31:13"
  ["chreseller_auth:"]=>
  string(18) "dom-cdmv-zs0f-mpwg"
  ["auth_info:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::1/hostname:"]=>
  string(12) "dns1.xxx.com"
  ["dns::1/hostip:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::2/hostname:"]=>
  string(12) "dns2.xxx.com"
  ["dns::2/hostip:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::3/hostname:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::3/hostip:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::4/hostname:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::4/hostip:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::5/hostname:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dns::5/hostip:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment:"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["inserted:"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution (post it into phpfiddle):

```
$text = "domain: xxx.de native_domain: xxx.de user: master status: active transfer_lock: yes auto_renew: yes delegation: yes ownerc: ASDASD1 adminc: ASDASD1 techc: ASDASD1 billc: FLOSCH2 created: 2015-08-25 10:31:08 modified: 2016-08-20 16:20:15 expire: 2017-08-25 10:31:13 chreseller_auth: dom-cdmv-zs0f-mpwg auth_info: dns::1/hostname: dns1.xxx.com dns::1/hostip: 1.1.1.1 dns::2/hostname: dns2.xxx.com dns::2/hostip: 1.1.1.1 dns::3/hostname: dns::3/hostip: dns::4/hostname: dns::4/hostip: dns::5/hostname: dns::5/hostip: comment: xxx inserted: 2016-01-29 23:46:29";

preg_match_all("/\S+/", $text, $matches);

$array = array();


foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
{
    if (preg_match("/:$/", $match))
    {
        $current_key = $match;
        $array[$current_key] = "";
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        $array[$current_key] .= ($array[$current_key] == "") ? $match : " $match";
    }


}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>";
```

So what happens is that I get everything that isn't a space, which means I get "domain:", "xxx.de", etc.

With each captured group, I check if it ends with a `:`, if it does, then it's the key, if not, then it gets saved into the dictionary with the key.

Not sure if the format is what you fully want, but I think you should be able to handle it from here.

PS: Change the text content if you wish.